# Composer require outdated source

Tags: php, composer-php

Why composer requires outdated files and not directly from Github repository?

Example:
Trying to require this repository: https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php

Tried in simple manner `composer require https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php` and it retrieves files from October 30th, 2019, and in Github it has update 7 days ago.

Tried --prefer-source, tried limiting in composer.json at repositories.

Is that the developer problem managing that repository? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is getting the latest **stable** release. The one tagged with version [2.8](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php/tree/v2.8).

If you want composer to retrieve the version hosted on `master`, you need to do two things:

Change the minimum stability in your `composer.json`, by adding this to the root of your configuration:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

And then ask explicitly for the development branch:

```
composer require ifsnop/mysqldump-php dev-master
```

Comment: Yes, explicitly calling for dev-master does download 2.8 version files, but that's pretty weird, because when you call any of 2.* versions u get old stable version which probably has either of 1.* tag. It should limit you to that stable version instead of changing composer.json to whatever you like.

Comment: That’s the way it works. Without specifying version, it will download the latest compatible tag.

Comment: Yeah well I did specify 2.8 version, and it gives me old source, that's why I asked in the first place.

Comment: If you specify 2.8; you’ll get the 2.8 tag. That is **not** the latest commit. If you want the latest commit, you need to get master.